# VS 2019 Build error : RDLCompile could not open file ".....rdlc"

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

Am trying to build my ASP.Net 4.5.1 project in VS 2019 , but am getting the below error for every rdlc file i have in my project .

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       RdlCompile: Could not open file "bin\Templates\SOMT_Template.rdlc". Could not find file 'C:\Incentivecomp\Main\QI_Admin\bin\Templates\SOMT_Template.rdlc'.  ICPS_Admin

But the same project is working fine in other machines , can anyone help me out?